# Linux permanently hung after running a grep command on "/sys/*" directory

Tags: linux, grep, sysfs

I ran the command:

```
sudo grep -r -i RETP  /sys/*
```

On two systems: Oracle Linux 7.5 server (256 GB RAM, 2 Intel® Xeon® Gold 6142 Processor) and on my desktop PC with Ubuntu 18.04 (16 GB RAM, Core i5-6400). In both scenarios, Linux OS hung!

Could you please explain why?

Comment: P.S> on virtual machines (VirtualBox) all fine, the problem occures only with Physical machines.

Comment: Does the whose machine hand, or just the terminal, that ran the command?

Comment: servers fully hung, not a treminal.

Comment: Parts of /sys/ tap into hardware and firmware. It would be dependent on your specific system model/brand anyway. Use known places. Eg, if looking for retpoline vulnerability, replace with `grep -r -i RETP  /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities`

Comment: yes, i know it, but i want to know the root cause of the issue. Looks strange.

Comment: Try finding what file exactly cause it to hang with `find /sys -type f | xargs sh -c 'for a; do echo $a; cat $a >/dev/null; done' sh`; the last one printed may be the culprit.