# Grep a String from Root Directory

Tags: grep

Is it possible to grep for a string that is hidden within multiple directories from the root directory of my server? For instance, if I SSH into my Ubuntu server and then want to grep for a certain string, but I don't know which subfolder it is in, can I just grep from the root directory?

Comment: You *can* but whether you *should* is a better question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470881/117549); you might or might not want to traverse NFS mounts or SMB mounts or...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but depending on how your server is set up, this might take a *very* long time (or never complete).  If you're absolutely sure the disks are all local you can execute:

```
grep --recursive --ignore-case "string" /
```

for more info:

```
man grep
```

Comment: My output from that is:

Comment: root@wavbyte:/# grep --recursive --ignore-case "sample" /
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Invalid argument
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush: Permission denied
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/stable_secret: Input/output error
grep: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/flush: Permission denied

Comment: It stopped searching after those outputs

Comment: Like I said: *...depending on how your system is set up...* in this case your user does not have access to those directories, but the command will continue searching the rest of the file system.  The answer did mention it *...might take a very long time...*  **;-)**

Comment: Sounds good. Yes, it is taking a long time.

Comment: @Fabby I have set up an IPv4 DNS with Ubuntu's GUI and I was wondering what file gets edited on the OS, so I'm running this: `sudo grep -rs "1.1.1.1" /` so it's been taking a few hours although it's a newly installed VM. I was wondering what you actually about `this might take a very long time (or never complete).` Why should it never complete?

Comment: @Shayan that would be [a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Provide much more detail on the server itself like the `fstab` and if that contains IP addresses or remote shares, provide a `ping -c 5 IP.AD.DR.ES` output for each and I can tell you.  The answer does say *it depends on your server setup*...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-r` option to grep recursively:

> Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.

On a typical system, it might not be a good idea, as grep doesn't have an option to not descend into mounted file systems. You would end up going through file systems like `/proc`.

Comment: Is it bad to go through system files? And why?

Comment: The `/proc` file systems contains files such as `/proc/kcore`. It is very large on 32-Bit systems and huge ob 64.Bit systems.

Comment: Ah.. that's why my `sudo grep -rs "1.1.1.1" /` command never finished, even after 16 hours lol.. Thanks for answering :)